# Update: Changing the color of Negative Predetermined Value Using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I am working on a project at work, where taking values (gross profit of catalogs over the course of a year) from a table from a CSV file using D3.js.

The idea is when a number is changed in a CSV file, the html format will change to the new value when refreshed. Example: today we made $xx.xx amount (which should be a style color green in CSS) but then the next day we make -$xx.xx (which the value will be a style color red because we are negative).

**Updated**:

This is the new code used to have more control over which tables will have a text color change if negative or positive:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
$( '#tableTwo tr' ).each(function() {
    $( this ).find( 'td' ).each(function() {
        //if cell value is less than 0, then change font color.
        console.log( $( this ).html() );
    });
});
});
```

which is suppose to change the predetermined value if negative, but received no errors and nothing changed. The script tag for this code is  below the table tag since d3.js is also on the bottom of the table tag. Reason for this, in d3.js have functions calling the divs in the html to place the data form the csv too:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jean.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div><h1 id = "headerFormat">Catalog 6F Matchback Report</h1> </div>

                <div id="firstCSV"></div>
                <div id="secondCSV"></div>
                <div id="thirdCSV"></div>
                <table id ="theSecretOne">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Labor Cost Parameter</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Labor Cost</td>
                            <td>7%</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>   

                </table>
                <div id ="fourthCSV"></div>
                <table id = "findMEPosition">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>report revenue /cost corresponds to catalog allocated revenue/cost</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div id="fifthCSV"></div>
                <div id="sixthCSV"></div>
                <div id="seventhCSV"></div>
                <div id="miscPosition"></div>
            <!--<script>
                $(document).ready( function(){
                    $("td.of_number_be_evaluated:contains('-')").addClass('red');
                    $("td.of_number_be_evaluated:contains('+')").addClass('green');
                });
            </script>-->

    </div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src="jean.js"></script> <!-- d3.js script to fill the table from the CSV file-->

<script type='text/javascript' src="numberColorChange.js"></script> <!-- color Change script-->
</html>
```

I have realized after placing a break point right before the jQuery code on Inspection page on Chrome, the D3.js is running after the jQuery code, which results in no change. Is there some type of function that can be used to delay the jQuery script, so that D3.js can place in the values to the table to be read?

Can anyone help me? If need more coding, I can provide more since using dummy data to see how long this project will take.

Comment: why is the jQuery code in your HTML commented? also would be great if you can share the jsfiddle demo

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with the developer console? Is your document.ready() function being called? Are the $('td')'s found? What is the cellValue.html()? Is there possibly a leading space that is throwing off your substring?

Comment: @ChrisG i have updated the main thread on the results which will answer your question

Comment: @Aziz i placed a comment there so it would be easier to see why the script is in that area. I scratched the old code for this new one since would help out for future projects, i do not have the jsfiddle avaliable now.

Comment: There is an easy solution using D3 only: when you create the element, set a class depending on the value, something like this: `.attr("class", function(d){ return (d < 0) ? "negative" : "positive"})`, and set the colors in the CSS according to those classes.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado   That worked perfectly! Thank you. The outcome also made the words in the table and numbers (the non monetary values in the table) to change colors. Is there a way to place these classes only to the gross profit numbers in one column using d3.js or should i just use nth-child in css to change the color for all monetary values?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but I have to see your D3 code...

Comment: I will post a question later today, for other new users using D3.Js and comment here where the question is located.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado here is the link to how the csv file is setup and the code i used     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009291/parsing-specific-columns-data-from-multiple-csv-file

Comment: @GerardoFurtado the code that you provide helped if the values in the csv are just numbers, but when i change them to a currency, all values (including the negative values) are positive. What is a good fix for that? I tried using d3.format while the csv file is in a number format, but became over complicated since do not know how to use the format

Comment: What do you mean by "change them to a currency"? Do you mean a string?

Comment: so original the format is "97" "-37", now  i change these values in excel as "$97" "-$37"  <-- this value in html is not shown as a negative but a positive even though the negative character is shown

Comment: Use a regex or something like that to get rid of the $ and convert the string to number. Or, even better: if the minus sign is always at the first position, use `indexOf` to check for the minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

So, I realized while playing with the CSV files data, EXCEL was changing the values to fit its structure when I wanted to change to different value (currency, number, decimal, etc). So, I opened the CSV files on Sublime Text to see how the values are actually formatted.

Then, I used Javascript from  [Use JQuery to Highlight Values in a Table](http://learnwebtutorials.com/jquery-highlight-values-table)

The colors changed perfectly fine even if I change the text in Sublime. Thank you every one who pointing me in the right direction.