# Parsing specific columns/data from multiple CSV file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

So, just recently I have been using D3.js to parse data from a CSV file. While reading the "Interactive Data Visualization" by Scott Murray (great book and very informative) it explains how to select all data from a table in a CSV.

The code to parse the CSV is shown below:

```
d3.text("three.csv", function(data) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);
            var container = d3.select("#thirdCSV")  
                .append("div")

                .append("table")
                    .attr("id", "tableThree")

                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")

                .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .attr("id","three")
                    .text(function(d) { return d; });

    });
```

For my project, I am taking 7 different CSV files and placing it on a HTML format.

Writing the code above 7x seems unnecessary, is there another way to parse multiple CSV file? If so, is there also a way to parse only specific columns such as columns D-F? Here is an image of how one of the files is set up (the rest of the CSV files are the same format.
[image: Table One]

Comment: wrap your code in a function where you pass in the non-repeating parts as arguments

Comment: So, you have 7 different CSVs? Why dont you create a single CSV, with these 8 rows?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado was thinking of doing that but each csv has its own role such as one is for gross profit, one for ,mailing cost, etc. How can I get better control over each table if in one csv?

Comment: Just bind each table to the specific dataset (subsets of `data`) you want.

Comment: @dandavis so  i started using the arguments with a function error, data and a random error code came up in the d3.v3.min.js library "Uncaught TypeError: n.charCodeAt is not a function". When i use the code above, the library is fine...

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific [function](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv) for reading in csv files in D3 `d3.csv()`. You should use it instead of `d3.text()` because it makes things much easier since you do not need to use `d3.csv.parseRows()` in addition. Look [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1525346) for example.

You can use `d3.queue()` [function](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue) for asynchronous loading of several data files. It waits for all the files to be loaded before the next steps are taken. You should use it like this:

```
var q = d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.csv, "first.csv")
    .defer(d3.csv, "second.csv")
    .defer(d3.csv, "third.csv")
    ....
    .awaitAll(function(error, results) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(results);
      draw(results)
    });
```

I also want to point out that the `D3.queue()` function is not included in D3 v3 default bundle, so you have to load it separately:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>
```